# MYSQL pick date from available date ranges closest to current date

Tags: mysql, date, syntax, range

I've a question regarding MYSQL queries, and how I could go about handling getting the closest date range to the current date...

So I have records in the form of id, from_date, until_date.

Given the current date, I would like to select the record that not only includes the current date, but if there is more than one record which meets the requirement, that the one which has its from and until dates closest to the current date, such that for example:

if:

```
record1: from_date1, until_date1
record2: from_date2, until_date2

from_date1 <= current_date <= until_date1
from_date2 <= current_date <= until_date2

from_date1 >= from_date2 and until_date1 <= until_date2
```

`record1` should be chosen...

I am looking for a select query syntax to achieve this...

I hope I am being clear enough in my example... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Piotr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT from_date, until_date
    FROM table
    WHERE current_date BETWEEN from_date
        AND until_date
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, from_date, until_date)
    LIMIT 1
```

selects all records who match the condition; the last one is not obeyed to 100% - what if `from_date2` is very close to `current_date`, but `until_date2` so far away that the time span is larger?